# Animate children inside StackPanel - WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, user-controls, storyboard

I have a StackPanel with UserControls as the children. I would like to apply a Storyboard animation which increases the height of the children from 0 to 100 in a second which creates a smooth slide down animation. This will be called for when a new child is added to the StackPanel - `StackPanel1.children.Add(usercontrol1)`. The StackPanel children are UserControls so I do **not** want to use DataTemplates. Below is an example layout of what I mean.

[image: example layout]

Could someone please help me create this as I have no idea how to make it. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how to create a Storyboard animation that will animate UserControl (children of StackPanel)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605709.aspx

Comment: Could you please explain more as whenever I've tried this before, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's more or less a copy paste from the link written in the comment above.
First, you need to create your control (let's say usercontrol1) and give it a unique name for the storyboard to reference it.

**EDIT:** Below is a code of a simple application that works:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="800"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel1">

    </StackPanel>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click">

    </Button>
</Grid>
```

and code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var usercontrol1 = new Label();
        usercontrol1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        usercontrol1.Content = "Hello";
        usercontrol1.Name = "UniqueName" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        RegisterName(usercontrol1.Name, usercontrol1);

        StackPanel1.Children.Add(usercontrol1);
        // Create a DoubleAnimation to animate the width of the button.
        DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        myDoubleAnimation.From = 0;
        myDoubleAnimation.To = 100;
        myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

        // Configure the animation to target the button's Width property.
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, usercontrol1.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Button.HeightProperty));

        // Create a storyboard to contain the animation.
        Storyboard myWidthAnimatedButtonStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        myWidthAnimatedButtonStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
        myWidthAnimatedButtonStoryboard.Begin(usercontrol1);

    }
```

Comment: I tried using the following code but it didn't work:
`UserControl1 child = new UserControl1();
child.label1.Content = "Some title";
stackPanel1.Children.Insert(0, child);
<the code you gave me>`

Comment: well, this shall be new UserControl1(); child.label1.Content... This is the way you get your control, depends on you business...

Comment: Where do I put my label settings for the UserControl then? I tried adding: 
`public void getMyNewControl()
        {

        }` but it gave me the following error: "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable"

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Instead, I am getting the error "'usercontrol1' cannot be found in the name scope of <project name>.UserControl1". That error appears on the line of `myWidthAnimatedButtonStoryboard.Begin(usercontrol1);`

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. It would be much simpler and quicker if you could create a simple WPF (C#) project with a StackPanel and a "Add" button (contains the animation code to add new child to StackPanel). Also add a UserControl which will be the animated child. This way you can see for yourself if it works or not.

Answer (score 2):

You need To target the object for the StoryBoard.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var usercontrol1 = new Label();
    usercontrol1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    usercontrol1.Content = "Hello";
    usercontrol1.Name = "UniqueName" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    RegisterName(usercontrol1.Name, usercontrol1);

    StackPanel1.Children.Add(usercontrol1);
    // Create a DoubleAnimation to animate the width of the button.
    DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    myDoubleAnimation.From = 0;
    myDoubleAnimation.To = 100;
    myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

    // Configure the animation to target the button's Width property.
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, usercontrol1.Name);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Button.HeightProperty));

    // **Set the Target Object for the Animation.**
    Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation, usercontrol1);

    // Create a storyboard to contain the animation.
    Storyboard myWidthAnimatedButtonStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    myWidthAnimatedButtonStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
    myWidthAnimatedButtonStoryboard.Begin(usercontrol1);

}
```